# Passing GridView Control IDs to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, aviary

I'm trying to implement a call to a Javascript function that appears within a Gridview in each row.  The code produces a button that can be clicked and brings up an Image Editor instance (Aviary by Adobe).

Because I don't have unique variable names then the same image is appearing each time, if I try to do this on a standalone page and change the Javascript variable names for each image the code works so I'm not sure what to do as I don't know how to make unique variable references.

I can't include the document.getElementByID parts inline as parameters to the function because I can't escape the single quotes.

The 3 javascript variables are

editImageControl 
editImageURL
editImageFilename

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit Photo">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Image ID="editImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "http://images.foo.com/" & Eval("filename") %>' CssClass="noDisplay" />
        <script>
            var editImageControl = document.getElementById('<%# DirectCast(Container, GridViewRow).FindControl("editImage").ClientID%>');
            var editImageURL = document.getElementById('<%# DirectCast(Container, GridViewRow).FindControl("editImage").ClientID%>').src;
            var editImageFilename = '<%# Eval("filename") %>';
        </script>

        <!-- Add an edit button, passing the HTML id of the image and the public URL of the image -->
        <p><input type='image' runat="server" src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor(editImageControl, editImageURL, editImageFilename);" /></p>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: why dont you this keyword to pass as parameter to function ,in that way,u can also reach the img id

Comment: There's definitely nicer ways to do it, but adding the `RowIndex` to end of the variables might be a quick fix, e.g. `var editImageURL<# DirectCast(Container, GridViewRow).RowIndex #> = document...`

Comment: I can't use that inline when I'm passing in the names into the launchEditor function thought Rhumborl

Sakir - I'm not sure what you mean sorry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind `editImageControl` use [Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ClientId`.  `Id` will give you a very long and cumbersome id, but it will be unique for every element (it's the full path for the control within the page's control tree).

```
  var editImageControl = document.getElementById(
        '<%# DirectCast(Container, GridViewRow).FindControl("editImage").Id%>');
```

Another option is to set the `editImage`'s `ClientId` when you define the control.  This way JavaScript can access it correctly.  I'm going to assume that `filename` is unique and is valid for storing as an html element's id (you might need to remove any path seperator or file extensions characters for this to work).

```
 <asp:Image ID="editImage" runat="server" ClientID='<%#Eval("filename")%>'
      ImageUrl='<%# "http://images.foo.com/" & Eval("filename") %>' 
      CssClass="noDisplay" />
```

Then you can use the same logic to set `editImageControl`:

```
var editImageControl = <%#Eval("filename")%>;
```

Comment: Is there a C# solution please, as DirectCast is a VB.net method