# Gridview row ids not generating after some action on page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a gridview with checkboxes. Am binding data to gridview in pageload. Upon selection of checkbox i am changing gridview row color by finding gridview row id (code written in javascript).

```
document.getElementById(gv_ctrl02).style.backgroundColor = "beige";
```

and gridview data rendering as below row ids.

```
table
tr id="gv_ctrl02" td 1000 /td td Anil /td  /tr
tr id="gv_ctrl02" td 1002 /td td Suri /td  /tr
tr id="gv_ctrl02" td 1003 /td td Jagan /td  /tr   
table
```

I have a button on my page and on click of it some action is happening. after that i check gridview rendred code it is not having row ids and below is my gridview rendered code

```
table
tr  td 1000 /td td Anil /td  /tr
tr  td 1001 /td td Suri /td  /tr
tr  td 1003 /td td Jagan /td  /tr   
table
```

As the rowids not generated, code for changing row color is not working.

```
document.getElementById(gv_ctrl02).style.backgroundColor = "beige";
//throwing Null javascript exception due to row id gv_ctrl02 is not available.
```

Comment: Can you clean up your question to format your code using Markdown.  It's very hard to read this.

Comment: And this sounds very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187778/unique-variable-names/27189964#27189964

Comment: Can you post your GridView markup on the server side? ASP.NET always generates ids for server side controls, so your problem looks really strange. That said, using generated ids in javscript is not the best of ideas, have you considered other ways?